# How to find the number of correct answers that user had made then convert the correct answer to percentage?

Tags: java, variables, primitive-types

There are 3 questions for user to answer. For example: if user had made all answers correctly, the code will show that "You got 3 correct answer and your grade is 100%"

```
    int x = ( int ) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int y = ( int ) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;

    System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " : ");
    int sum = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (sum == (x+y)) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    else {System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }

    System.out.println( x + " * " + y + " : ");
    int mult = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (mult == (x*y)) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    else {System.out.println("Wrong!");

    }

    System.out.println(x + " - " + y + " : ");
    int minus = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (minus == (x-y)) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
```

Comment: To increment value stored in variable use `variable = variable + 1`. With this information you should be able to count how many questions  was answered correctly (you can also count how many questions there ware in total). Now you need to divide `correct/total` and multiply it by 100. (try to think which types to use for your variables - what type of data should be returned when you divide). Now try to write your code and ask question when you will get some problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, declare some variables to work with for your test.

```
Integer userScore=0;
Integer totalScore=0;
```

The percentage is userScore/totalScore*100.  To add these up throughout the test, each of your questions should have something like this in them.

```
if (answerIsCorrect) {
    userScore++;
}
totalScore++
```

To get the percentage, you just need to use your variables that have been created like so:

```
percentage = userScore/totalScore*100
System.out.println("Your percentage: "+percentage.toString());
```

Comment: yes, thank you! it's work flawless and i had change some of code too!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to keep track of the number of questions asked and the number of correct answers. Declare the following variables at the top of your code:

```
int questions = 0;
int correctAnswers = 0;
```

Each time you print out a question, increase the question count. For each correct answer, increase the correctAnswer count. Finally after all questions are answered:

```
int percent = (correctAnswers * 100)/questions
```

For example if they got 5 correct answers out of 10 then percent would contain the integer value 50. Then simply output it to the user:

```
System.out.println("Your percent correct is:" + percent);
```

Comment: wow i didnt realize that we can use the same integer as many time as we want, (sorry because i'm new to java) so what mean is just add the "int question and correctanswer" into each branching (i mean after if(){ int....} right?